# Why are there two structures of L-Glucose in the Fischer projection?

Tags: stereochemistry, carbohydrates

We are told that L-Glucose is an enantiomer of D-Glucose, which would mean that they are mirror images of each other. But then we're also told that the L and D forms is determined by the spacial relationship to glyceraldehyde. 
[image]

Which of the structure is correct? Are they the same?

Comment: Strictly on the left there is not a projection. It is a projection like every other structural formula

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like the left one is just wrong.
It looks like who made the image took D-glucose and just flipped the 5-OH.

The result? The molecule at left is not glucose, but L-Idose!